# pkexec on WSL Error

Tags: xfce, windows-subsystem-for-linux, pkexec

Launching `pkexec synaptic` in the below environment fails.

**My PC specsare:**

xfce desktop
ubuntu 18.04 on WSL
VcxSrv for X server

---

Here is the output:

```
~$ pkexec synaptic
Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Could not connect: No such file or directory
```

Is this error expected? Any fix available?

Comment: What version of ubuntu? What are you using for X?

Comment: pkexec uses the PolicyKit infrastructure which does not seem to work on WSL. Simply start synaptic with "$ sudo synaptic"

Comment: @Panther i have updated my query with the required information.

Answer (score 1):

Open Synaptic in WSL using the following command:

```
sudo -H synaptic &>/dev/null
```

Note that you need to use `sudo` in order to give Synaptic root permissions that are required to install software , remove software , etc.