# Sudoers file syntax error on WSL

Tags: command-line, permissions, sudo, windows-subsystem-for-linux

So, I've messed up my sudoers file in the windows subsystem for linux. I was trying to add something, and the guy of the tutorial said to edit sudoers file with nano/vim, and that's what I did (later I discovered that you should only edit it with visudo, nice). When I saved, I realized I couldn't use "sudo" anymore, the terminal would complain saying:

```
>>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 33 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 33
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

I've read a bunch of articles saying that I would have to run:

```
pkexec /usr/sbin/visudo
```

But the result was always the same:

```
Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Could not connect: No such file or directory
```

I tried everything, spent like two hours reading stuff and couldn't do anything. Can anyone help me? As you can see, I'm clearly new when it comes to real linux.

Comment: Actually if you were using "real linux" this would be relatively easy to solve, either by dropping to a root shell from grub, or by using a live USB. I don't know if there are equivalent mechanisms for WSL (I haven't found them).

Comment: Yeah, `pkexec` unfortunately [seems to be missing/broken on WSL](https://askubuntu.com/q/1065960/367990).

Comment: What is in line 33? Add the details in question. I generally use `EDITOR=nano visudo` command.

Answer (score 46):

I found quite a simple solution for my case.

Just open Windows console (cmd), then:

```
wsl -u root visudo
```

And fix the file.

Note that `visudo` does not catch all errors.  To avoid getting locked out of `sudo`, keep a root shell (`sudo -s`) or `visudo` open until after you've thoroughly tested your new config.

Answer (score 1):

On my side because the command `wsl -u root visudo` did not worked, I used the following alternative:

I changed the default user to be root by following the instruction in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/966537/11473):

```
ubuntu config --default-user root
```

then restart `LxssManager` service (from services.msc)

When I open the WSL, by default is connect as root and I can safely execute the command `visudo` from that WSL instance.

I corrected the bad entry and saved it.

My WSL was starting fine after the correction.

Just in case, here is the default `sudoers` file I had in the beginning:

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    mail_badpass
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification
%sudo ALL=NOPASSWD: /sbin/start-stop-daemon
%sudo ALL=NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/ssh

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

It's possible that some entries have been added by "apt install" command.

don't forget to switch back to the original user after the operation:

```
ubuntu1804.exe config --default-user <username>
```

The command `ubuntu1804.exe` can be adapted to your distro (20.04, others linux, etc...)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but for future readers' sake, please, please **don't do this**.  Even if it "works", it's bad practice for at least four reasons.  First, but least importantly, it only "works" on WSL1, not WSL2 (the WSL2 filesystem is stored in a virtual `.vhdx` disk image).  Second, you should use `visudo` instead of editing the file directly.

Comment: Next, you should avoid editing Linux files (which use Unix-style LF line-endings) with Windows tools (which typically create and edit files with incompatible CRLF line-endings).  While Notepad++ is smart enough to handle *some* cases, I've still seen a number of questions raised here on the Stack Exchange Network where problems were caused by creating or editing Linux configuration files in WSL with Notepad++ or other Windows tools.  The only Windows tool that I would consider safe for this would be Visual Studio Code, when launched from within WSL.

Comment: Finally, and most importantly, (copying from [Microsoft's advisory](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/)) **There is one hard-and-fast rule when it comes to WSL on Windows:**  *DO NOT, under ANY circumstances, access, create, and/or modify Linux files inside of your `%LOCALAPPDATA%` folder using Windows apps, tools, scripts, consoles, etc. Opening files using some Windows tools may read-lock the opened files and/or folders, preventing updates to file contents and/or metadata, essentially resulting in corrupted files/folders.*

Comment: *"in my case I found that easier than just re-installing everything"* - The highest voted answer on this page avoids installation, and is safe.  I'm glad it worked out for you, but future readers here should *not* follow your example.

Comment: Actually, the first answer *did* give the file, but since modifying it directly is considered bad practice, the mods agreed to an edit to *remove* that from the answer.  The `visudo` command edits *that* very file, but [does so much more safely](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/27594/432493).  Also, the `wsl -u root` will still work when the sudoers file is corrupted.

Comment: Really should be a new question, because that wouldn't be a `sudoers` problem, but if you have problems with your root's `bash` configuration that prevent you from launching WSL normally, then you could still run apps using the `wsl -e` (a.k.a. `wsl --exec`) *as* the shell, rather than *in* the bash shell.  So several options, including `wsl -u root -e sh` (to run the `dash` shell (without going through `bash`), or `wsl -u root -e vi /root/.bashrc` (a possible cause of the problem), or `wsl -u root -e sh -c 'vi ~/.bashrc'`.

Comment: Googled *bin/bash invalid option gnu long option*.  The first result was [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17136853/11810933).  Most likely cause for that particular error is that the script (likely `.bashrc`) ended up with DOS line endings ...

Comment: I just tested this solution on WSL2 and it worked. Thx!

Comment: @AntoineWils thanks for your comment, this solution works for both but the accepted answer is quicker. I wrote this answer because before WSL 2, the powershell command wsl.exe was not compatible with the accepted answer. I also edited this answer in order to prevent the modification of the linux file from Windows as mentioned in the (now deprecated) comments.

Answer (score 0):

Close the WSL terminal, open Windows command prompt and make the default WSL user as root using the below command

```
ubuntu2004 config --default-user root
```

Open a new WSL terminal, you will be logged in as root.
Type

```
nano /etc/sudoers
```

Now you can edit the sudoers file. Cheers!

Extra: `ubuntu1804 config --default-user root` for Ubuntu 18.04 and above or `ubuntu config --default-user root` for versions below.

Comment: You must make non-root user back as default.

Comment: Hi @Sajid-Ali.  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  While I appreciate your attempt, yours is really a duplicate of the first answer (with 23 upvotes).  The correct command (`wsl -u root`) is listed in that answer.  Yours does the same thing, but with more effort, using an older command (`ubuntu1804`) that Microsoft doesn't recommend be used any longer.

Comment: Also, for @Kulfy who edited it - Even if you *do* use the `ubuntu` commands, you have it backwards (sort of).  The `ubuntu` command is used if you just installed the "Ubuntu" (latest version) from the Microsoft Store.  Depending on *when* you installed the latest, this might be 16.04, 18.04, or 20.04.  However, it's also possible to install a specific version from the Store, like `ubuntu1804` or `ubuntu2004`.  The reason is that these are all just "App Execution Aliases".  This is one reason that Microsoft created the replacement `wsl.exe` command, which is one that should really be used now.

Comment: On my side it worked but I had to restart LxssManager service in order to make the change user to be effective when switching to root, otherwise it still connect with the previous user.