# Can't change the owner back to the root (can't use sudo command) in WSL Ubuntu

Tags: permissions, sudo, root, windows-subsystem-for-linux, chown

I faced this issue when I want to use `sudo` command :

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers is owned by uid 1000, should be 0
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

then I tried a solution from a similar question in order to change the owner back to the root:

```
$ pkexec visudo
```

also I tried this one

```
$ pkexec chown root:root /etc/sudoers /etc/sudoers.d -R
```

but I have faced another issue with these commands:

```
Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Could not connect: No such file or directory
```

**So is there a solution to this issue?**

Full shell issue snippets:

```
ubuntu@LAPTOP-D4T16P7J:~$ sudo -i
sudo: /etc/sudoers is owned by uid 1000, should be 0
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
ubuntu@LAPTOP-D4T16P7J:~$ pkexec visudo
Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Could not connect: No such file or directory
ubuntu@LAPTOP-D4T16P7J:~$ pkexec chown root:root /etc/sudoers /etc/sudoers.d -R
Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Could not connect: No such file or directory
```

This is my /etc/sudoers file:

```
ubuntu@LAPTOP-D4T16P7J:~$ cat /etc/sudoers
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

**OS info:**

- Ubuntu WSL2.

Comment: Possible way:  https://askubuntu.com/a/1153161/231142

Comment: What should I edit in /etc/sudoers file?

Comment: Shouldn't have to edit it, but change ownership of it.  `chown root:root /etc/sudoers`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Terrance , It works!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer was as follow:

- access root user by issuing this command in windows command line (CMD):

  ```
  wsl -u root
  ```
- change ownership of /etc/sudoers file to the root:

  ```
  chown root:root /etc/sudoers
  ```

**Thanks** to [@Terrance](https://askubuntu.com/users/231142/terrance) for him help.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issue.

using `wsl -u root` resulted in error.

Open cmd, run `wsl -l` to get distribution name.

In my case output was `Ubuntu-18.04`

run `wsl -d Ubuntu-18.04 -u root`

You should be using root now.

run `chmod 440 /etc/sudoers`